# "Update Required" show when i on server in webRTC in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

require('webrtc.io').listen(8001) ; turn on the server on 127.0.0.1:8001 but when i open it on browser it shows "Update Required" ? How to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This means that you are listening only for HTTP on this port and not for websocket. You need websocket for this to work.

Comment: can you provide some more detail? I am new in this field. I am trying var webrtc = require('webrtc.io').listen(8001);
// step 1 create instance of server
"use strict"
var http = require('http');
var websocket = require('websocket').server;
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){

});
var wsServer = new websocket({
 httpServer : server
});
wsServer.on('on',function(request){
 console.log("Hello");

});
//server.listen(8001); but it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I have got my error . I need to open index.html in browser because i am trying to make a http connection to a websocket server .

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Hii</h2>
<script src="./webrtc.io.js"></script>
<script> rtc.connect('ws://127.0.0.1:8001');

  rtc.createStream({"video": true, "audio":false}, function(stream){
    // get local stream for manipulation
    rtc.attachStream(stream, 'local');
  });

  rtc.on('add remote stream', function(stream){
    // show the remote video
    rtc.attachStream(stream, 'remote');
  });
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```